# Using internal method call in constructor? (Basic)

Tags: java, constructor

Here is the exact instruction on what my professor has asked me to do:
Write a constructor with two parameters for int year and String player.
Use internal method call to setDetails to initialize the fields.

I have the class so far like this:

```
public class Card
{

    private int year;
    private String player;


    public Card(String player, int year)
    {

    }
}
```

Not sure what the internal method call is, I have looked on the internet and StackOverflow and have not found anything that has benefited me. Any help is appreciated.
 Thank you,
 A first year programming student.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: What is the rest of your code? The code you provide means nothing to us.

Comment: Probably `this.setDetails(...)` . setDetails is probably a private (internal) method of your class.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I fixed it and added the entire code for the class.

Comment: @Jonasw that was my first guess but I wasn't sure. I added the entire code for the class to help people understand my question more.

Comment: There is no point in using method to initialize constructor unless any calculation is involved.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Assignment instructions. I agree that it's a bad idea, especially since then the fields can't be final (and player cards should be immutable), but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You need a method to set the details of the card, like this:

```
private final void setDetails(int year, String player) {
    this.year = year;
    this.player = player;
}
```

And then in the constructor, you can call `setDetails(year, player)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement here is the code that you 're asking for:

```
public class Card {

    private int year;
    private String player;

    public Card(String player, int year) {
        setDetails(player,year);
    }
    /*i'm making it public in case you want to call the setter directly 
    somewhere and final since i call an overridable method in the constructor*/
    public final void setDetails(String player,int year) {
        this.player=player;
        this.year=year;
    }
}
```